# How to create nested listview with searchbar in android toolbar?

Tags: java, android, search, toolbar

I tried this code and doesn`t return my inputed text.
This is my Addtocartitems.java :

[image][image]

This is my Downloadeditems.java :

[image]

This is my DownloadedListAdapter2.java :

[image]

This program has no error but nothings happened.
Can anybody help me please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Create the list variavble in adapter class**

```
List<DownloadedItems> downloadedItemsList= new ArrayList<>();
```

**inside your constructor please call write down this**

```
public DownloadListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<DownloadedItems> object){
    super(context,resource,object);
    this.mcontext= context;
    this.mResource=resource;
    this.downloadedItemsList= object;
}
```

create the method in adapter which gets the list

```
    public void  setData(List<DownloadedItems> modelList) {
    this.downloadedItemsList= modelList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Now call the filter method with new filtered list and pass that list to adapter method

```
private void filter(String text) {
    List<DownloadedItems> filteredList = new ArrayList<DownloadedItems>();
    for (DownloadedItems la :langList) {
        if (la.langName.toLowerCase().startsWith(text.toLowerCase())) {
            filteredList.add(la);
        }
        adapter.setData(filteredList);
    }


}
```

You can change the method .startsWith to .Contains as of your requirement. This method returns the items which starts with the entered string. langList is the initial list which i have passed already to the adapter to present.

```
la.langName.toLowerCase().startsWith
```

this is the filter query , the item which i am using to compare to filter. I am searching the language name from the list. So you can modify according to your requirement.and call the method filter from

```
 mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            filter(newText)
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: sir, can you translate in java?

Comment: converted to java

Comment: replace the class LanguageModel to your list model.

Comment: Sir, Where can i add filter method?

Comment: inside mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener where you had adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

Comment: Where did you get langList?

Comment: that is the list you are passing to the adapter

Comment: Sir, where did you get languageModelList?

Comment: you are using this adapter for recyclerview.??

Comment: I`m not using recyclerview sir

Comment: so what are you using for this view?

Comment: where are you using the adapter.?

Comment: Actually I`m using listview w/ another listview on it. Im using that adapter for my 2nd .xml which is my 2nd listview.

Comment: can you write down the code where you are getting the list and setting the adapter in activity?

Comment: if you face any problem, please share your skype id, i will talk to you there...

Comment: please do not post the picture of code, instead write the code...here

Comment: you should use recyclerview instead of listview, recyclerview is more advanced.

Comment: For now, im using listview.

Comment: create chat discussion , to further discuss about this